# CSS selector using two attributes (both required)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to target an input element where there is another input element with the same ID (hurray, React!), but with a different `type=` attribute.

How can I select this selector?

```css
input{width:100px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
    <input id="bob" type="text" value="Not me" />
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <input id="bob" type="hidden" />
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <input id="bob" type="email" value="Found Me" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two attribute selectors side-by-side:

```
element[attr1="value"][attr2="value"]{background:yellow}
```

In the below example, all three input fields have the identical ID (*yes, I know that is "not allowed", but... React*).

##### Example:

```css
input{width:100px;}
#wrapper input[id="bob"][type="email"]{background:yellow}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
    <input id="bob" type="text" value="Not me" />
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <input id="bob" type="hidden" />
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <input id="bob" type="email" value="Found Me" />
  </div>
</div>
```